# How to set Conky to auto hide like gnome toolbar

Tags: gnome, conky

Is there a way to configure conky to pop out when I move my mouse to the right of the screen and hide when I move it away like the gnome toolbar? I'm on Ubuntu 20 Desktop.

Comment: You might be able to program something yourself using `xdotool behave_screen_edge`.

Comment: I managed to set up a panel to include Conky that pops out on mouseover in the Xfce DE using the [Embed](https://docs.xfce.org/panel-plugins/xfce4-embed-plugin) panel plugin. If there's a Gnome panel applet similar to Xfce's Embed plugin, the same might be possible in Gnome.

Answer (score 0):

A review of the [Conky](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/wiki) [configuration](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/wiki/Configurations) options and [window options](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/wiki/Window-Configuration) does not show that capability. The closest I could find was to display conky results only in a terminal, the [GNU Screen](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/wiki/Window-Configuration) option described in window options, but that won't roll up to hide as the GNOME toolbar does.